# entanglement of different types of particles possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Perhaps this question makes no sense physically, but is it theoretically possible to entangle a photon with an electron, for example?

I know that entanglement links a specific property of particles, but is there any property that maps across particles, e.g. spin, that can be entangled across particles?

As an side, I heard that, in the original German, Schroedinger (?) used the word **entwinement** which got translated to entanglement in English.  Unfortunate, since  entwinement sounds so much better.

Comment: _Entwinement_, that's interesting Benito. It reminds me of winding numbers. And pair production, and [TQFT](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=tqft+knot+theory&tbs=li:1), which is linked to knot theory. Like, _an electron is a 511keV photon entwined with itself_. And in annihilation two such fermions with the opposite chirality "unentwine" each other. I must [have a look for that](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=electron+photon+entangled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

States may be entangled and by extension we say that the particles with these states are entangled. Entwinement is a nice word but it hides a little the basic meaning.

In the references of 
[Quantum entanglement between an optical photon and a solid-state spin qubit](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v466/n7307/full/nature09256.html#ref1)

you may find

> *Several recent experiments demonstrated entanglement of optical
>   photons with trapped*
>
> **ions**
>
> - *Blinov, B. B., Moehring, D. L., Duan, L. M. & Monroe, C. Observation    of entanglement between a single trapped atom and a
>     single photon.    Nature 428, 153–157 (2004)*
>
> **atoms** :
>
> *Volz, J. et al. Observation of entanglement of a single photon with
>   a    trapped atom. Phys. Rev. Lett. 96, 030404 (2006)* 
>        *Wilk, T., Webster, S. C., Kuhn, A. & Rempe, G. Single-atom    single-photon quantum interface. Science 317, 488–490 (2007)*
>
> **and atomic ensembles :**
>
> *Yuan, Z.-S. et al. Experimental demonstration of a BDCZ quantum
>
>   repeater node. Nature 454, 1098–1101 (2008)*
>         *Matsukevich, D. et al. Entanglement of a photon and a collective    atomic excitation. Phys. Rev. Lett. 95, 040405 (2005)*
>         *Sherson, J. F. et al. Quantum teleportation between light and matter.    Nature 443, 557–560 (2006)*

This kind of entwinements, following the theory, is used to stock superposed states, ie from a photon to defaults in a crystal.

Precisely, for a photon and an electron, you can read [Demonstration of quantum entanglement between a single electron spin confined to an InAs quantum dot and a photon](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5555)

> *In this letter, we report an all optical experimental demonstration of
>   quantum entanglement between a single electron spin confined to single
>   charged semiconductor quantum dot and the polarization state of a
>   photon spontaneously emitted from the quantum dot's excited state.*

Comment: Beat me to it, but I'll add my refs too since they've just been published recently: 1. http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/151124/ncomms9955/full/ncomms9955.html (also http://phys.org/news/2015-11-physicists-quantum-photons-messages-electrons.html); 2. http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/1/10/e1501015 (also http://phys.org/news/2015-11-quantum-entanglement-room-temperature-semiconductor.html); 3. http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v526/n7575/full/nature15759.html (also http://phys.org/news/2015-10-universe-weird-landmark-quantum.html).

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to create a quantum radar with the reference photon in a spool of fiber optic cable ... https://hackaday.com/2019/08/26/quantum-radar-hides-in-plain-sight/#comment-6175231